# Multiple webroles in azure

Tags: .net, azure

I am creating azure project with multiple webroles for multiple websites.
When I Deploy this I am getting single url (*.cloudpp.net)

How to get url(*.cloudapp.net) for each role.

Answer (score 2):

Every Windows Azure application gets one virtual IP address (and one CNAME mapped to it, like <foo>.cloudapp.net).

Roles within an application can listen on different ports on that one IP address (e.g. http://<foo>.cloudapp.net, port 80, and https://<foo>.cloudapp.net, port 443).

If you want different IP addresses, you'll need to create multiple applications, not multiple web roles within the same application.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to host several websites on the same url, you can host them on different ports (with one port for each webrole). If you wish to have them all on the same port, you need to serve all the sites out of the same webrole, but with different hostheaders for the various sites, or you can run them as virtual directories. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg433177